# gulp js doesn't concat css

Tags: css, gulp

dont know why but i can't concat my css file with gulp:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concatCss = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('concat',  () => {
  return gulp.src('assets/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("bundle.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('bundle'))
  })
```

when i run 'gulp concat' in powershell the bundle folder remains empty, but the procedure seems work fine:

```
[20:17:22] Starting 'concat'...
[20:17:22] Finished 'concat' after
```

i'm new to gulp, many thanks

Comment: run the task without the concat step and verify the output to the bundle folder. (i.e. remove the line `.pipe(concatCss("bundle.css"))`), so that we can narrow down the problem

Comment: So 'assets/css/*.css' is relative to your gulpfile.js location.  Is there something there?

Answer (score 0):

solved, I have had to set the relative path:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const minify = require('clean-css');



     gulp.task('default',  () => {
          return watch('./asset/scss/*.scss',()=>{
            gulp.src(['./asset/scss/main.scss','./asset/scss/*.scss'])
            .pipe(concat('bundle.scss'))
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./asset/css'))
            })
          })
```